# Rails: How to enable users to create a record but requires admin approval before posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, authorization, admin, cancan

This is similar to a question I asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516454/rails-how-to-handle-requiring-different-administrator-approval-depending-on-th), but I didn't really understand where my actual confusion was. I've looked at CanCan for defining custom level permissions, but what I am unclear how to do is how to allow normal users to create whatever they want, but before the actual records are created, an admin must come in and authorize it.

For example, Users can create Projects, and these projects have to belong to a particular State. My administrators each belong to a particular state, and they have to approve any new projects created in their state. Is there a way to do this with CanCan, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow all users to create projects, but allow only admins to approve them. And on projects index page you can list only approved projects.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :create, Project

    if user && user.admin?
      can :approve, Project
    end

  end
end
```

Projects controller:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.where(approved: true)
end

def approve
  if can? :approve, Project
    @project.update_attributes approved: true
  end
end
```

I assume that new projects are created with `approved: false`.

Answer (score 0):

Its your application logic.

You should have a table or a flag-field that tells if the Project is approved.
Normal users would only see approved projects

```
def index
   @projects = Project.where(approved: true)
end
```

(or use a default_scope)

And Admins would have a list for approving his own states projects

```
def approve_list
   @projects = Project.where("approved = ? AND state_id= ?", false, params[:state_id])
end
```